# Web API - Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, wcf, token

Uma aplicação MVC faz acesso a serviços WEB API.

Para acessar o WEB API é necessário obrigatoriamente informar um "token".

Na aplicação WEB API existe um botão que gera o token.

**Como fazer que o WEB API aceite apenas o token gerado através da aplicação MVC sem usar banco de dados?**

Eu fiz o MVC gerar o token (um GUID + data) e passo este token para o WEB API que valida se a data esta dentro de um período de 30s. Se estiver dentro do período considero que o token é valido.

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
DateTime when = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));

if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-30))
{
    return false;
}
```

Isto funciona, entretanto, qualquer GUID que for informado concatenado de uma data será válido. **Preciso fazer com que o meu WEB API saiba exatamente qual token foi gerado pela aplicação MVC**.

Comment: Olá Alberto, tente explicar melhor o que você necessita.

Comment: Você pode substituir o GUID por uma chave que só o projeto MVC conhece. Mas não entendi porque tem um botão para gerar o token se só um outro projeto pode conhecer o token.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Estive pesquisando um pouco e acredito que o que preciso seja um OTP. Ou seja, o MVC gera um token e o outro projeto sabe qual foi o token gerado.

Comment: Já pensou em usar o `OAuth` que já faz tudo isso pra você? Dá uma olhada aqui: http://www.leonardohofling.com/blog/web-api-adicionando-autenticacao-oauth/

Comment: Recomendo que você utilize JWT / OAuth. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3 Caso queira utilizar o Azure AD para isto, eu gravei um video que talvez te ajude: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSkY1PbkrfA&list=PL3tw-QzEqu8QS8lopRA_KpTs5DJvFm1ks

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas soluções para o seu problema...

1. Ao gerar o token na aplicação MVC, envie ele para a WebAPI (Através de um endpoint restrito, que só você tenha acesso), ao receber o token, sua API vai armazenar ele na memória em uma lista/dicionario estático. O problema é que você não pode matar o processo ou reiniciar o servidor onde está a WebApi e quando a Pool (se estiver usando IIS) reiniciar, todos os dados serão "perdidos". (Neste caso, ficaria mais fácil ainda você criar o token direto na WebAPI e criar um endpoint restrito que só o MVC acesse para obter o token, a cada acesso gera novo token e exclui os inválidos da memória [collection/list/dictionary/hashset])
2. Adicione um SALT (uma string aleatória, pré-definida, de conhecimento exclusivo das aplicações) ao seu token, codifique ele com SHA1 ou outro algoritmo de encriptação (neste caso, você nem precisa do GUID...)
3. Uma solução nada segura, porém eficaz para o seu problema seria, um SALT + GUID + data, tudo isso codificado em Base64, porém como disse, isso não é nada seguro, e qualquer um com conhecimento intermediário, que visualizar o token vai perceber que é uma string base64 e pode passar ela em um decodificador de base64 e ver o padrão original sem maiores complicações...
4. Implemente OAuth ou JWT (mas tenho impressão que para isso, obrigatoriamente irá precisar de um banco de dados).

Porque você não pode utilizar um banco de dados ? Nem um noSQL está autorizado ? Porque não faz isso utilizando o Redis ?